# Reading a text file stored in mobile phone storage using React-Native

Tags: android, react-native

I want to read the content of a text file stored inside the downloads folder in an Android phone. How can I do this using React-Native?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [react-native-fs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fs):

[Sample usage](https://dev-yakuza.posstree.com/en/react-native/react-native-fs/):

```
...
// typescript style
import * as RNFS from 'react-native-fs';
...

// readFile(filepath: string, encoding?: string)
RNFS.readFile(filePath, 'ascii').then(res => {
    ...
})
.catch(err => {
    ...
    console.log(err.message, err.code);
    ...
});
...
```